# Issue with running See3Cam via pycharm

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu, pycharm

So the code works but when the screen pops up it's all black. Can't see any images. I thought my code wasn't picking up the camera but when i ran the external application for the camera (while the code was still running) it said the camera is being used somewhere else (assuming its PyCharm because when I stop the code it works on the external application).

I also tried running the cameras external application prior to running the code but when i do that the code gives me errors. I also tried running the code without the camera plugged in but gives me an error. So I'm assuming it picks up the camera but cant give me an output.

```
 import cv2
 print("done")

 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 if not(cap.isOpened()):
    print("cant open")

 cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
 cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

 while(True):
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('preview',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF==ord('d'):
        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it is possible that there is an error in your code, but I think, it's more likely that PyCharm has not got the permission to use your Camera. Try to open cmd(look in the search bar, it's preinstalled) and open it as Administrator. I'm sorry that I can't test it, but I don't have a webcam in my computer.

Comment: Hey, not sure what you mean by open cmd? is that just the abbreviation for command?